# Using query and filter in sqlalchemy to modify User table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

New to sqlalchemy.

I am trying to figure out how to best use query and filter to select a specific User based on entries under the created instance e.g. 'a.create_user('guy', 'Joe', 'Smo', ...) (as shown in a.retrieve_user(some username, ... some password) that I created for Users.

I created a class called BaseModify that I want to use to access the functions I have created to retrieve them based on the correct username/password combo; I also want to update them based on calling retrieve_user (which if correct) can then be updated. I tried the code below, but it prints out the user regardless of correct parameters which is very problematic. Any explanation of help is truly appreciated.

Create User works here... I've adjusted thanks to some help on here.

```
class BaseModify(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = Session()

# Create User

    def create_user(self, username, password, firstname, lastname):
        new_user = User(username, password, firstname, lastname)
        self.session.add(new_user)
        self.session.commit()
        print(username, firstname, lastname) 

  def retrieve_user(self, username, firstname, lastname):
        users = self.session.query(User).\
        filter(User.username == username).\
        filter(User.firstname == firstname).\
        filter(User.lastname == lastname).all()
        for user in users:
            print(user.username, user.firstname, user.lastname)

    def update_user(self, username): 
        up = self.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
        print up.username
        if up:
            up.username = username
            new_username = up.username 
        return new_username
        self.session.commit()


    def delete_user(self, username, password):
        deluser = self.retrieve_user(username, firstname, lastname)
        if deluser:
            self.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).\
            filter(User.firstname == firstname).\
            filter(User.lastname == lastname)
            self.session.delete(User)
            self.session.flush() 


""" instantiate (create) instances of the API below: """

a = BaseModify()

#create  
a.create_user('dance', 'cats', 'Jas', 'Lo') 
a.create_user('wizzard', 'linux', 'Bree', 'Jane')

a.retrieve_user('dance', 'cats')  
a.retrieve_user('wizzard', 'dogs')   
print(a)
```

I've made updates to the top. Trying to simply change the username through "update_user" and "delete_user" by calling the "retrieve" method to clean the code up. From what I understand, query/filter is to search through the tables and then the remainder of the code is python doing something. That right??? Best practices??

Answer (score 1):

For me it is not completely clear what you want to do with each of the methods, but there are few mistakes that are easy to solve and below I try my best from what I understand from your post. If you explain what you want a bit further, the errors you get and what you expect, I may improve my answer accordingly.

- method `retrieve_user`

First you should correct it, you are not using the parameters passed to the method,

```
def retrieve_user(self, username, password):
    found = select([User.username]).where(User.password == password)
    users = self.session.query(User).filter(User.username.in_(found)).all()
    for user in users:
        print(user.username)
```

Note that you could also write the subquery `found` like this:

```
    found = self.session.query(User.username).filter(User.password == password)
```

Anyway, to me it does not make sense you fetch a user just by checking the password, I guess it would make more sense to do something like,

```
def retrieve_user(self, username, password):
    users = self.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).filter(User.password == password).all()
    for user in users:
        print(user.username)
```

- method `update_user`

Similarly,

```
def update_user(self, username): 
    up = session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
    print up.username
    up.username = username
    self.session.commit()
```

(although obviously with this method you are not doing much, you should pass username and new_username to the method, and do `up.username = new_username`)

And in the second version of `retrieve_user` in your post, I'm also a bit lost, I don't know why you want to retrieve the users you already have in your session, but anyway you are missing the equalities in your `filter` statements.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**: improved version of `update`, after some comments.

```
def update_user(self, username, new_username): 
    up = self.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
    if up:
        up.username = new_username
    self.session.commit()
```

I'd suggest you read [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session.html) for some guidelines on the session.

Comment: thank you! Sorry for the confusion. It stems from my confusion about how to work with the query method. Is it better to retrieve_user based on username, ID, and first/last name?

Comment: As for updating, I would want to update username. So something like this: def update_user(self, username): 
up = session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
print up.username
new_username = up.username 
up.username = username
self.session.commit()

Comment: Glad it helped. As for `retrieve_user`, well, it depends on the application, if you are validating the login or just trying to find the user. What is your primary key in the table? As for the `update` method, once you fetch the user and store it in `up`, it belongs to `sqlalchemy` session, and whatever you do will be in your session, and committed to database when you do `commit`.

Comment: @Irnzcig The goal of **retrieve_user** is to validate login and then to adjust username in **update_user** and **delete_user**. I updated per your suggestion... See my comments and changes. Thank you SO MUCH for helping me better understand this.

Comment: No problem. Just some advice, please consider it for next time: it is better that you leave your question as it is, so that it might help somebody else that bumps into a similar problem in the future. If somebody posts an answer that solves you problem, then what you should do is to accept the answer, leaving your question untouched. (You only modify your question when you need to clarify your problem).

Comment: Aww... I see. Will do in the future. Sorry about that! New to this awesome site.

Comment: And about best practices: if you want a peer review of your code, please post a question at [SE code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). But just quickly, about your code I would tell you that you don't usually do `commit` or `flush` to your session everytime you do a modification. You could maybe read [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session.html)

Comment: as for the update method... did I implement it correctly? For SQL, do you have to return?

Comment: No problem, I can guess you are new and I'm just trying to explain. It is indeed an awesome site.

Comment: Ok, I didn't read in detail your implementation of `update`... Have you tested it? I don't think it will work, no. Please wait a minute for an update in my answer.

Comment: Aw! I get it. Even though I have made the changes in the DB via **update_user** I still have to remove the former since it remains in the db's session. Thanks again @lrnzcig